# Terminal limits scrolling

Tags: command-line

I have a running log, it outputs a lot to the terminal. Unfortunately, when I try to scroll up and view older output, it appears there is a limit. And I am unable to scroll past a certain point. On the Mac, the terminal allows you to scroll up to the start of the session. Is there a way to do this in ubuntu terminal?

Comment: `konsole`, the terminal program from KDE, has a setting to control the number of "scrollback" lines it remembers, including Unlimited setting. I suppose Gnome terminal should have something similar but I can't check at the moment.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Go to `Edit` -> `Profile Preference` -> `Scrolling Tab`

Now just tick the `Unlimited` box below `Scrollback`.

You will now be able to see your entire output.

[image]

Comment: @JohnMerlino If the answer was useful to you, Consider upvoting the answer

Comment: where find `Edit` option.???

Comment: In your Menubar

Comment: @vineet_sah: There's no 'edit' in my menu bar.  Instead, I right-click inside the terminal and select "Profiles -> Profile Preferences"

Comment: what about with ubuntu server without UI?

Comment: Is there any danger to the "Unlimited" setting? Like e.g. running out of memory?

Answer (score 16):

Since the question is now over three years old, I just want to post an update:

In Ubuntu 15.10 it is pretty similar to the accepted answer, there it looks the following:

- Go to `Edit` -> `Profile Preference` -> `Scrolling` Tab.
- Untick the box beside `"Limit scrollback to:"`.

[image: Disable "Limit scrollback to:"]

Comment: Is there any danger to the unlimited setting? Like e.g. running out of memory?

Answer (score 2):

Supposedly Gnome terminal has an option for that, please check Edit->Profiles->Default->Edit->Scrolling->Scrollback

Answer (score 1):

The other answers here are correct... unless you use the `clear` command. Sometime after Ubuntu 12.04, running clear also prevented scrollback, even if you have the terminal set to unlimited scrolling. This can be very frustrating.

For a discussion and workarounds, see [How to stop `clear` from clearing scrollback buffer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/792453/how-to-stop-clear-from-clearing-scrollback-buffer)

Answer (score 1):

## Ubuntu 22.04

The default number of scroll back lines in Ubuntu 22.04 is `10000`. You can change this to any number up to `2147483647` or disable it altogether. Both can be done either from the GUI or from the command line.

### From the GUI

Open *Terminal* -> *Settings* (the hamburger button) -> *Preference* -> *Profiles* -> *Unnamed* -> *Scrolling*. There you will see *Limit scrollback to*. You can either disable it altogether or change the number of lines you want to scroll back like this:

[image: Preferences - Profile Unnamed]

### From Command Line

The same thing can be done from the command line, using `gsettings`. Read more about how this works in this post: [How to change gnome-terminal scrollback lines from command line](https://askubuntu.com/a/1492529/1157209).

Enable unlimited scrollback:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.Terminal.Legacy.Profile:/org/gnome/terminal/legacy/profiles:/:$(gsettings get org.gnome.Terminal.ProfilesList default | tr -d \')/ scrollback-unlimited true
```

Limit scrollback to 250,000 lines:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.Terminal.Legacy.Profile:/org/gnome/terminal/legacy/profiles:/:$(gsettings get org.gnome.Terminal.ProfilesList default | tr -d \')/ scrollback-lines 250000
```