# How to change konsole scrollback lines from command line on Kubuntu?

Tags: command-line, 22.04, kubuntu, konsole

with `Kubuntu 22.04.3 LTS x86_64`
the 179 character command below, did not work.

refer:
[How to change gnome-terminal scrollback lines from command line](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1492528/how-to-change-gnome-terminal-scrollback-lines-from-command-line/1492529#1492529)

```
gsettings set org.gnome.Terminal.Legacy.Profile:/org/gnome/terminal/legacy/profiles:/:$(gsettings get org.gnome.Terminal.ProfilesList default | tr -d \')/ scrollback-lines 250000
```

2 outputs from above 179 character command:
`No such schema “org.gnome.Terminal.ProfilesList”` and
`No such schema “org.gnome.Terminal.Legacy.Profile”`

Explain and
what is the correct command to
change scrollback from command line?

--

Comment: You've tagged your question `gnome` and `gnome-terminal` but mention that you are using Kubuntu (which would be based on KDE and Konsole) - please clarify what Ubuntu flavor and terminal emulator you are actually asking about

Comment: What command answers Ubuntu flavor? and What command answers terminal emulator?   
```neofetch --stdout |grep 'OS:'``` gives ```Kubuntu 22.04.3 LTS x86_64```  and   
```neofetch --stdout |grep 'Kernel'``` gives ```Kernel: 6.2.0-37-generic``` and 
```echo $TERM``` gives ```xterm-256color```   and 
```ps -o 'cmd=' -p $(ps -o 'ppid=' -p $$)``` gives ```/usr/bin/konsole```   and 
```pstree -sA $$``` gives ```systemd---sddm---sddm-helper---startplasma-x11---plasma_session---kded5---konsole---bash---pstree```  and 
```ps -p $PPID -o comm=``` gives ```konsole```

Comment: The `gsettings ...` commands stated in the original questions are specific for the GNOME Desktop which Ubuntu is using, they will not work for Kubuntu and the KDE Desktop.